# Persistent resolution using xrandr in VNC

Tags: xrandr

I have Linux PC which is remote and boots up in text mode.  I do access X on this machine via VNC. 
However I do have requirement to resize the resolution ( different monitors ). I know xrandr is meant for this.

However whenever I add new mode using xrandr, it is not persistent across reboot. I see people mentioning a startup script sort of implementation for xrandr add-mode/new-mode, Is there any other way around.

I am aware of xorg.conf file, however it is support to work if X is started isn't it ?
On boot, xrandr shows couple of different resolutions, from where it does pick them ?

Answer (score 0):

Created script and added in startup 
To derive X params

```
gtf 1850 1150 60
```

To Add new Mode

```
xrandr --newmode "Name" <Output of Above Except Modeline "xxx_yyy_Hz" >
```

To Add mode into display

```
xrandr --addmode "VNC-0" "Name"
```

To set desired display

```
xrandr -s "Name"
```